# Check checkbox if i write something in a input type text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m trying to make a form that looks like this:

[image]

where if inside of the input type ="text" is something like a number auto-check the CHECKBOX, is jquery? or simple PHP.

Ahh, the more important thing, I'm using woocommerce, so i make the function like that.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');


function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {




    woocommerce_form_field( 'losung', array( 
        'type'          => 'text', 
        'class'         => array('my-field-class'), 

        'label'         => __('titel'), 
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter a number'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));
        echo '<div class="spiele-container">';
        echo '<input class="input-checkbox pull-left" id="" type="checkbox" name="ter">';
        echo '<div id="text-container-spiele">text ';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or something?

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP in this case, it's a jquery/javascript thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" class="something" />
<br>  
<input type="checkbox" name="check" class="check">
```

JS:

```
$("input[type='text']").on("keyup", function(){
    if(this.value!=""){
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", "checked");
    }else{
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', ""); 
    }
});
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/anANoSof/1/

Cleaner solution would be to use a class/id for the text-field as well as the checkbox and use like :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" class="num" />
<br>  
<input type="checkbox" name="check" class="check">
```

**JS**:

```
$(".num").on("keyup", function(e){
    if(this.value!=""){
        $(".check").prop("checked", "checked");
    }else{
        $(".check").prop('checked', ""); 
    }
});
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/iWESuTa/1/

As per @Fred, to disable the user from clicking the checkbox manually, simply use the `disabled` attribute as follows :

```
 <input type="checkbox" disabled name="check" class="check">
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/iWESuTa/2/

Comment: That's what i want, but, if you delete the text, still appears the checkbox checked,

Comment: Good answer! What would be a good addition is to prevent the checkbox from being selected if there is no text entered. What risks in happening here is, if someone checks the checkbox, there might be an empty value sent, which I doubt the OP would want. (Just saying) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery code.

consider you have id `tbox` for textbox and id `cbox` for checkbox.

```
$( "#tbox" ).keypress(function() {
    $('#cbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

keypress is the function that will trigger when a character is entered in the textbox.

the prop function is jQuery 1.6+.

Answer (score 0):

well, this a JS task ( mostly everything going on without page reload is about JS). Using jQuery the code u need is something like

```
$(function(){
  $('.my-field-class').keyup(function(){
    var $cb =  $(this).parents('form:eq(0)').find('.input-checkbox');
    if(this.value != '')
      $cb.attr('checked', 'checked');
    else
      $cb.removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
```